# How to successfully import a .csv file into phpmyadmin

Tags: csv, import, phpmyadmin

I'm working on something and i want to import a csv file into my database.
I know the basic step of importing but not getting that data properly into my table columns. Here is the pic of .csv that i want to import.[image]

This is what i'm getting.[image]

Comment: Okay , what's your proplem exactly?

Comment: i have updated my answer with a picture of my problem. pls do check!

Comment: This was answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627873/7511165

Comment: ok, let me try that.

Comment: I have tried this but the problem remains..

Comment: Please insert in the question the content of csv file